# It was raining: было vs шёл

Tags: перевод

If I want to translate

> Today is raining

I learned that I can say

> сегодня идёт дождь

But let's say I want to translate

> Yesterday it was not raining.

I would say:

> 1) вчера не шёл дождь

But on different sources I have seen

> 2) вчера не было дождя

Is there a difference between these two constructions or are they equivalent?

Comment: "Bчера не было дождя" is "Yesterday it did't rain." That's all.

Comment: So it's the same as "вчера не шёл дождь", isn't it?

Comment: "вчера не шёл дождь" looks perfectly grammatical, but unnatural for the native speaker.

Comment: `вчера дождь не шёл` sounds better, in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

A very interesting observation. Indeed, people tend to say **дождя нет** instead of **дождь не идёт**, in the present tense as well.

The reason is tricky. "Properly", you'd have to use the negative genitive here: *дождя не идёт / дождя не шло.* But people intuitively shy away from impersonalising a verb like **идти** which is almost always used personally (i.e. with a subject). So these two conflicting demands — "you need a negative genitive" and "an impersonal **не шло** sounds rather odd" — find a fairly standard compromise in falling back on a form of **не быть** instead.

A more recent development of the negative genitive is that its absence (i.e. using the nominative or accusative instead) conveys a sort of definitiveness, much like an article. Thus **Вы не видели велосипеда?** is "Have you [by any chance] seen a bicycle?", whereas **Вы не видели велосипед?** is "Have you seen *the* bicycle?"

In much the same way, modern Russian parses **вчера не шёл дождь** as talking about "the" rain, in whatever context that might be. (And further context would be required to justify the word order, as opposed to the more natural **вчера дождь не шёл**, putting the new information last.) "The rain" is clearly a regular occurrence here whose absence yesterday was unusual.

And these grammatical indications are intuitively clear, giving speakers another reason to prefer a simple **вчера дождя не было** if all they want to say is that it didn't rain yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

`вчера не было дождя` - sounds the most natural

`вчера дождь не шёл` - sounds legitimate but does not roll from the tongue

However!

`вчера снег не шёл` - sounds the most natural

`вчера не было снега` - totally confusing without context, is it about snow on the ground or in the air?

Answer (score 1):

both phrases mean the same. `вчера не было дождя` sounds more natural if you want to express the absence of rain.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding `дождь не идёт` is a generalized phrase, while `дождя нет` is a little more specific: it is not raining right now, although we are well aware of the bad weather and wouldn't be surprised if it rained any moment.

I guess it may be approximated with English progressive tense:

`дождь не идёт` → it doesn't rain

`дождя нет` → it is not raining